# Existing angular web-app into wordpress page

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, single-page-application

I created an angular single-page web app for my customer.

Now they need to integrate the app into a page of their (wordpress) website.

EDIT: in other words they want the app inside an existing wordpress page

what's the best approach?

I tried iframe but it does not work: no resize on app content change and problems with modals.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you need to insert it in an existing page with an already done template you can create a **shortcode** and a **plugin**:

create a folder like "your_spa" in the plugin folder of wordpress (/wp-content/plugins/)

create a php file named your_spa.php inside the new generated folder

put this inside the file "your_spa.php"

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: your spa plugin
Description: description
*/

function your_spa_code(){ ?>

<!-- put here your code (this will be inside the body of the page) -->

<?php }

add_shortcode( 'yourspa', 'your_spa_code' );
?>
```

take care of the links/resources urls (js, json, css): place them anywhere you want them, but remember the path (like in html path => url)

remember to let the apache user read the files (file permissions)

activate the plugin "your spa plugin" inside the wordpress dashboard

use [yourspa] inside a blogpost/page as a shortcut

And now you have created a plugin and a shortcode!

PS: remember that your code will be surrounded by the code of the existing page

It's a little dirty but it's the easies solution.

Comment: I need my app included in an existing wordpress page

Answer (score 1):

I had some success with simply rendering Angular's bootstrap code, the `<app-root>` and `<script>` tags, just as they are served from a standalone an Angular deployment.

I just added the following HTML in a post, using the HTML editor.

Of course, I had to fiddle the JS script source URLs.  Rendering all this HTML could be done with a Wordpress shortcode and plugin that asks for a URL path to the JS files.

```
<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js"></script>
```

This worked poorly with the Divi theme and a 'code' module, totally screwed up the page.  Attempts to use the offical Wordpress mechanism for including JS scripts (`wp_enqueue_script`) failed since the `<app-root>` tag can't be found when the scripts load.